# Nginx redirect specific page with data to another page using data

Tags: nginx, redirect

i have tried a few diffrent things i have found on this site but cant seem to get any working

i am lookin to redirect using nginx from one media file to another while using the arument data to build the other url

my first url looks like so

```
http://domain:port/video/media.php?mediaid=00000
```

i need to use that url to redirect to

```
http://domain:port/mediaid/dash/playlist.mpd
```

this is the last thing i have tried and it kind of works but still contains /video/ before the wanted url

```
    if ($arg_mediaid) {
        rewrite ^/video/(.*) ^/$arg_channelId/dash/playlist.mpd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not stripping `/video` from the URL. You are just matching on it.
Either update the existing regex or try adding this rewrite rule after your current rule.

```
rewrite ^/video(/.*)$ $1
```

This strips away the `/video` bit from the path and replaces it with whatever comes after `/video/` which will be your, `/$arg_channelId/dash/playlist.mpd`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach:

```
location /video {
    try_files /$arg_channelId/dash/playlist.mpd =404;
}
```

It is best to avoid `if`, because it has all kinds of side-effects.